# populating IEnumerable collection with a List<string> data

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have an existing List that countains data

```
List<string>countries
```

I want to somehow loop through this data an populate the following collection

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries
```

How would I go about in doing this?

Comment: You can't. IEnumerable is just for enumerating. When you want to add something you need an instance or interface that allows adding.

Comment: What's your `SelectListItem` definition?

Comment: @AndreiV It could be [`System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.aspx).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, point taken. Still, it's a bit ambiguously formulated. The answer could be more specific if the type definition were known.

Comment: @AndreiV Absolutely. That information was missing, so your comment was relevant. My comment was simply a guess, meant to be helpful.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I didn't see your comment in any other way than that :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method I can think off is using a Linq query:

```
Countries = countries.Select(country => new SelectListItem {Text = country, Value = country});
```

You won't have the ability to differ the text from the value, however.

Comment: Select returns an IEnumerable

Comment: Note that this is correct but does not "populate" a collection. It justs defines a LINQ query which would be executed everytime you _use_ it. So you might want to add a `ToList()` which returns a `List<SelectListItem>` which is also an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming this is related to mvc... try this

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries = countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c, Value = c });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I think.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries = countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem
              {
                  Text = c,
                  Value = c
              });
```